# Oracle- Error when running stored procedure, only in normal mode

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a problem with a stored procedure in Oracle DB.
When i try to run this procedure in Job, or i try to call it from sql window by 'exec', it returns error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated-parent key not found
```

So, everything should be clear- i tried to add a child row, without parent row.
The problem is, that when i run same function in DEBUG mode (just after i received error when running it by 'exec'), and i go thru it step by step everything is fine...

Body fragment, which is generating error:

```
 if length(v_plik_kursu_a)>0 or length(v_plik_kursu_c)>0 then
  --sprawdź, czy istnieje wpis dla bieżacego dnia
  select count(*) 
  into v_licznik
  from tabele_kursow_walut tkw
  where 
     tkw.id_tabeli_kursow='NBP'
     and to_char(tkw.data,'yyyy-mm-dd')=to_char(v_data,'yyyy-mm-dd');

  if v_licznik=0 then
     insert into tabele_kursow_walut tkw
     (id_tabeli_kursow,data,urzedowy_numer_tabeli,blokada)
     values
     ('NBP',trunc(v_data),'NBP','N');
  else
     select data
     into v_data   
     from tabele_kursow_walut
     where
        id_tabeli_kursow='NBP'
        and trunc(data)=trunc(v_data);
  end if;

  for i in '1' .. v_liczba_walut 
  loop

     select count(*) 
     into v_licznik
     from kursy_walut tkw
     where 
        tkw.id_tabeli_kursow='NBP'
        and to_char(tkw.data,'yyyy-mm-dd')=to_char(v_data,'yyyy-mm-dd')
        and tkw.kod_waluty=currency_array(i).name;

     --raise_application_error(-20000,v_data||' - '||currency_array(i).name||' - '||currency_array(i).average_rate||' - '||currency_array(i).purchase_rate||' - '||currency_array(i).selling_rate);

     if v_licznik=0 then
        insert into kursy_walut kw
        (id_tabeli_kursow,data,kod_waluty,kurs_sredni,kurs_kupna,kurs_sprzedazy)
        values
        ('NBP',v_data,currency_array(i).name,currency_array(i).average_rate,currency_array(i).purchase_rate,currency_array(i).selling_rate);
     else
        update kursy_walut kw
        set kurs_sredni=currency_array(i).average_rate,kurs_kupna=currency_array(i).purchase_rate,kurs_sprzedazy=currency_array(i).selling_rate
        where 
           id_tabeli_kursow='NBP' and data=v_data and kod_waluty=currency_array(i).name;
     end if;

  end loop;
  commit; 
 end if;
```

Stored procedure is not defined as AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.
Error Appears at:

```
insert into kursy_walut kw
    (id_tabeli_kursow,data,kod_waluty,kurs_sredni,kurs_kupna,kurs_sprzedazy)
    values
    ('NBP',v_data,currency_array(i).name,currency_array(i).average_rate,currency_array(i).purchase_rate,currency_array(i).selling_rate);
```

Kursy_walut is a child table of tabele_kursow_walut .

Constraint which is generating error is created on table `kursy_walut`

Constraint name is: `KWL_TKW_FK`

Referenced table is: `TABELE_KURSOW_WALUT`

And referenced columns are: `ID_TABELI_KURSOW`, `DATA`.

Error from database looks like: `ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated (my_schema_name.KWL_TKW_FK) - no parent key found`

And just to remind the problem, Everything is working fine when i debug this procedure, i get no errors that way, but when it is running by: job for example, i see `ORA-02291` error.

Comment: When inserting/updating a table which has a parent-child relationship, ensure parent key does exist in the parent table. Without the description of the table structure, it would be difficult to allude which table column or line in the procedure is erroneous.

Comment: In my opinion its not possible that parent row is not being created, firstly i check if there is any row in parent table, and if it doesnt exist im inserting one. Problem is between table Kursy_walut and tabele_kursow_walut. There is no more tables.

Comment: Exactly this fragment is returning error:

 insert into kursy_walut kw
        (id_tabeli_kursow,data,kod_waluty,kurs_sredni,kurs_kupna,kurs_sprzedazy)
        values
        ('NBP',v_data,currency_array(i).name,currency_array(i).average_rate,currency_array(i).purchase_rate,currency_array(i).selling_rate);
     else

Comment: Encapsulate the procedure code with the exception block. Thus it would be easy to identify which line or statement has the error.

Comment: Does `kursy_walut` has a parent or child table or in other words, a relational table having a foreign key?

Comment: Yes, its called: KWL_TKW_FK

Referenced table is: TABELE_KURSOW_WALUT

And referenced columns are: ID_TABELI_KURSOW, DATA.


Error from database looks like:
      ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated (BAZA_BPSC.KWL_TKW_FK) - no parent key found

Comment: Please describe `kursy_walut` by editing the question

Comment: Does `NBP` and  value for `v_data,currency_array(i).name` exist in `TABELE_KURSOW_WALUT`

Comment: When i run this procedure, its actually not, but the code in question, should create it. And yes, parent row which contains values: `NBP` and `V_DATA`. Currency name is not part of foreign key, so there is no column like it in `tabele_kursow_walut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to catch the exception in the PLSQL block, make necessary changes as deemed as the below is pseudo code

```
  DECLARE
   l_parent_not_found   EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (l_parent_not_found, -2259);
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO kursy_walut kw (id_tabeli_kursow,
                               data,
                               kod_waluty,
                               kurs_sredni,
                               kurs_kupna,
                               kurs_sprzedazy)
        VALUES ('NBP',
                v_data,
                currency_array (i).name,
                currency_array (i).average_rate,
                currency_array (i).purchase_rate,
                currency_array (i).selling_rate);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN l_parent_not_found
   THEN
      -- try printing the values which are on the insert statements
END;
```

Comment: ok, i got an exception again, and i printed out first 3 columns, separated by `;`
Data is: 
`NBP;18/11/21;USD

NBP;18/11/21;CHF
NBP;18/11/21;GBP
NBP;18/11/21;EUR
NBP;18/11/21;PLN
NBP;18/11/21;CZK
NBP;18/11/21;AED
NBP;18/11/21;AUD
NBP;18/11/21;SEK
NBP;18/11/21;BGN
NBP;18/11/21;CNY
NBP;18/11/21;RSD
NBP;18/11/21;RUB
NBP;18/11/21;UAH
NBP;18/11/21;ZAR
NBP;18/11/21;INR
NBP;18/11/21;EGP
NBP;18/11/21;MYR
NBP;18/11/21;SAR`

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Analyse the data which prints in the exception block, co-relate with the data in the parent table. It should be matching cent per cent.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik By the way, the second column on the insert statement which is data, is this a `date`  data type?

Comment: Yes, it is declared as: `   v_data           date; `

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Perhaps, this is of some [help](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::YES:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:1330002539879)

Comment: Ok, i found an error, when i was running procedure with sysdate, the date contained hour, minutes, and seconds. and when i was adding row in parent table, i used trunc, but when i was inserting `kursy_walut` i didnt used the trunc function, so thats why parent row did not existed.
What is more funny, when i ran this function in the PLSQL DEVELOPER, i selected date manually, and the date was correct, because it doesnt contained additional data, which is `hour` `minute` `second`

Comment: Thank you for your time @Jåcob

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik I suspect that was the error and hence the question about date data type.

Comment: When i ran procedure like : `procedure_name(sysdate-5)` it failed everytime, but when i ran it like `procedure_name(trunc(sysdate-5))` it succeed.
Thats why when i tried debugging, it was successfull everytime, because parameter window, doesnt put hour and minutes into the data parameter.

It makes sense, because parent row with date like : '18/11/26 15:32:00', will never exist, because in insert to `tabele_kursow_walut` im truncating this data. And when making an insert to a child table im not using trunc function.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Seldom have seen date data type as foreign key.

Comment: Thats true @Jåcob, thats why i couldnt come up with solution alone (i wasnt thinking OUT OF THE BOX :) ),btw. im not owner of these tables, my task was to fill it with data from web service. Again thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with date parameter (v_data).
When i ran procedure like : `procedure_name(sysdate-5)` it failed everytime, but when i ran it like `procedure_name(trunc(sysdate-5))` it succeed. Thats why when i tried debugging, it was successfull everytime, because parameter window, doesnt put hour and minutes into the data parameter.

Parent row with date like : '18/11/26 15:32:00', will never exist, because in insert to `tabele_kursow_walut` im truncating this data. 
Unfortunatelly when im making an insert to a child table im not using trunc function.

Thanks for help @Jåcob